# Java AES implementation issue "Illegal key size" with 32 byte key

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I am attempting to perform AES encryption using Java.

I have a key size of 32 bytes represented by 64 ASCII characters. (I want to perform AES with a 32 byte key which I believe is AES 1024 bit)

```
byte[] key = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("03d42e229a8992a195a7bc0789a0fb6636cc5edeb0f106c8ca0d843b269f5396");
```

When I call the below method, I receive the following:

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters
```

Here is my method in Java

```
public static byte[] AESDecryption(byte[] key, byte[] data)
    {
        byte[] retval = null;
        try 
        {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding", "SunJCE");


            SecretKeySpec thekey = new SecretKeySpec(key,"AES");

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, thekey);

            retval = cipher.doFinal(data);


        } 
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (NoSuchProviderException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return retval;
    }
```

Comment: Yup! thank you just found it!

Comment: I will delete this question, thanks!